# How to display Custom Posts on a WordPress homepage?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There are a lot of questions on the internet right now on how to display custom posts on a WordPress page. I followed the tutorial from [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type).

**1. I registered a custom post**

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');

function portfolio_register() {     
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Portofoliu', 'portfolio'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Adauga proiect', 'portfolio item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Adauga un proiect la portofoliu'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );     
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      );      
    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}
```

**2. I registered the taxonomy**

```
register_taxonomy("Skills", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Platforme", "singular_label" => "Platforma", "rewrite" => true));
```

**2. My front-page code is:**

```
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>  
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
                // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php else :
                // Show the default message to everyone else.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>
            </article>

        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have the Custom Post and Taxonomy on my admin, but how to display this on my **Portfolio** page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(

                'taxonomy' => 'Skills',

                'field' => 'id',

                'terms' => '27'  // disfine your category id 

            )
        ),
        'post_type'=>'portfolio',
        'order_by'=>'date',
        'order'=>'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1   //no of post -1 for no limit
);
    query_posts($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
    <li>
        <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li> 
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php 
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio'
        );

        $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = NULL;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>  
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
                // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php else :
                // Show the default message to everyone else.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>
            </article>

        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In My front-page code is: code before

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

use 
follow the WordPress codex for this
[query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. This code works for me:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'ENTER YOU POST TYPE HERE'); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

the_content();

endwhile;
```